Is it possible to get separate framebuffers for displays on Nouveau?
I'm using a simple Nvidia GPU (gt730) to run desktop system on a home server. I'm using nouveau as the GPU driver built-in on the 6.9 latest kernel.
I use FBDEV (on /dev/fb0) to run the X server. /dev/fb0 is nouveaudrmfb.
From recently, I have a need to run two separate physical users at the same time. I installed the second monitor, and I understand how to configure Xorg for specific Mouse/Keyboard devices.
But there is a problem. When installing the second monitor, I expected a /dev/fb1 device to be registered. But nouveau is not doing it! There are even no logs from it when the second monitor is plugged in. And the second monitor is just showing the same contents as the first one. The /dev/fb0 device now writes to both of the screens.
But I don't want it, I need a separate framebuffer for the second X server. Is it possible without a 2nd GPU?

"Two separate physical users at the same time" is called a multiseat configuration, and you'll probably need to start by writing some udev rules to designate which bits of hardware should be assigned to the second, non-default "seat". Unfortunately the virtual console subsystem still supports only one seat, but with X11 or Wayland you should be able to do it. Google for multiseat <name of your distribution> to hopefully find some instructions.
